# JPMS Module System Issue

Tags: java, command-line-interface, java-platform-module-system

I created 2 random modules I exported "com.alice" package from **folder A** and require the module in **folder B**. Then compiled A: `javac mod10/A/module-info.java mod10/A/com/alice/Ship.java` and tried to compile B `javac mod10/B/module-info.java mod10/B/com/alice2/Main.java`. And I get this:

```
error: module not found: com.alice
        requires com.alice;
                    ^
1 error
```

why I get "module not found" error message?
Shouldn't it be the whole point of exporting a module to make it visible to other modules?

In mod10/A/module-info.java

```
module com.alice {
             exports com.alice;
}
```

Ship.java

```
package com.alice;

public class Ship {
    private String name;
    public Ship() {
        this.name = "Ship Created"; 
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

In mod10/B/module-info.java

```
module com.alice2 {
             requires com.alice;
}
```

Main.java

```
package com.alice2;

import com.alice;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

      Ship x = new Ship();

      System.out.println("Ship made" + x.getName());
    }

}
```

Folder Tree:

```
mod10 (root)
 |_ A
     |_ com
         |_ alice
             |_ Ship.java
     |_ module-info.java
 |_ B
     |_ com
         |_ alice2
             |_ Main.java
     |_ module-info.java
```

Comment: *Shouldn't it be the whole point of exporting a module to make it visible to other modules?*  - Where are you exporting a module?  - The second module needs to know where is the first module present.

Comment: In mod10/A/module-info.java I exported it. So, if I export a module do I need to export it explicitly to a module which I want to know about it? E.g.: by using exports moduleName to moduleName; Is that what you mean?

Comment: I think you need to include module A in the modulepath of module B. See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/java.htm) on how to use `--module-path`.

Comment: @dan1st is correct -- the modules are described correctly but at run time, B has no idea that A even exists or where to find the jar.